# Sorting a nested dictionary with paired names

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary in Python of the following format:

```
docs_info = {
  "6": {
    "031546386": {
      "o_name": "Michael",
      "n_name": "Palin"
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "020245492": {
      "o_name": "John",
      "n_name": "Cleese"
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "021027690": {
      "o_name": "Terry",
      "n_name": "Gilliam"
    },
    "040474564": {
      "o_name": "Terry",
      "n_name": "Jones"
    },
    "031336583": {
      "o_name": "Eric",
      "n_name": "Idle"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display it in a specific format.

The iteration should use the keys in ascending numeric order (starting with `"2"`, then `"3"`, etc.). The keys of the dictionaries in the next level are ids, and should be sorted alphabetical order, and each of its values it should print both the `o_name` and `n_name` values.

The wanted final result should be:

```
John Cleese
Terry Gilliam
Eric Idle
Terry Jones
Michael Palin
```

From a previous thread I learned that we can use the following syntax to get the first iteration:

```
for key, value in sorted(docs_info.items()):
```

But I have a problem to understand how to iterate in the nested inner structure.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just add another `sorted()` loop over the `value` dictionary, same as the first loop:

```
for key, value in sorted(docs_info.items()):
    for id, inner in sorted(lvl1.items()):
        print(inner["o_name"], inner["n_name"])
```

Because you don't need to use the `key` and `id` variables in your loops, it is better to use the name `_` for these, to indicate that you intentionally are ignoring them. Python linters will then not complain about the name not being used.

You also may want to use a different name for the second level of dictionaries, other than `value`, and if you want to sort the keys *numerically* you need to convert those keys to integers first as you sort:

```
for _, lvl1 in sorted(docs_info.items(), key=lambda kv: int(kv[0])):
    for _, inner in sorted(lvl1.items()):
        print(inner["o_name"], inner["n_name"])
```

Demo:

```
>>> for _, lvl1 in sorted(docs_info.items(), key=lambda kv: int(kv[0])):
...     for _, inner in sorted(lvl1.items()):
...         print(inner["o_name"], inner["n_name"])
...
John Cleese
Terry Gilliam
Eric Idle
Terry Jones
Michael Palin
```

You can combine the whole thing into a single list comprehension:

```
sorted_names = [
    (inner["o_name"], inner["n_name"])
    for key, lvl1 in sorted(docs_info.items(), key=lambda kv: int(kv[0]))
    for id, inner in sorted(lvl1.items())
]
```

However, it is perhaps not as readable and so much more friendly to future maintainers to *not* use the above construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
for _, value in sorted(docs_info.items()):
  for _, inner_value in sorted(value.items()):
    print(inner_value['o_name'], inner_value['n_name'])
```

Comment: You are not sorting on the names, however.

Comment: Did I misread the spec?  Does it say I should?  I just understand it as: sort the outer, then for each sort the inner, then print o_name and n_name.

Comment: I see now that *both interpretations* lead to the exact same output. I've asked for clarifications.

Comment: It actually solves my problem but It should be opposite sorted

Comment: You can use `sorted(…, reverse=True)` then.

Comment: Or do you mean the inner values should have precedence in sorting?  First sort by the inner keys and only if these are equal, sort by the outer keys?  Your post for sure didn't state that.